# Counting number of perfect matchings

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, perfect-matchings

Counting perfect matchings in bipartite graphs is $\# P$ complete. Let $G(V,E)$ be a graph known to have $d$ number of perfect matchings. Bipartite it the obvious way by adding $E$ vertices with one vertex splitting each edge.

Is counting the number of perfect matchings in the new graph $\# P$ complete?

Comment: Usually new graph have unequal parts

Comment: Per Fedor, if the subdivided graph has a perfect matching then every component has a unique cycle. For such graphs computing the number of perfect matchings can be done in linear time.  Alternatively, subdivide each edge of $G$ with two new vertices. Now the number of perfect matchings is the same as for $G$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Can you explain the linear time algorithm?

Comment: Consider one component, which consists of a cycle with trees attached to each vertex. A leaf edge must be in the p.m., so repeatedly remove leaf edges and both their vertices. If an isolated vertex occurs, the count is 0. Otherwise it will end when there is nothing left or just the cycle left. If nothing is left the count is 1, if an odd cycle 0, even cycle 2. Multiply the counts for each component. It's obviously polynomial. To achieve linear time, it needs a good data structure to keep track as the leaf edges are removed.